# PHP:Can't retrieve line by line text from a text file with php

Tags: php

I have a text file in my server which changes dynamically and i wanted to print specific line of the text file in my php page also i wanted to trim the current line.
For example,Assume data.txt

```
score=36
name=Football Cup
Player=albert
```

and i wanted to print like this in my page
    36
    Football Cup
    albert

So how can i print specific words or sentence from a text file which is dynamically changes.

Answer (score 3):

In this case it looks like all you need is:

```
foreach(file("data.txt") as $line) {
    list($k,$v) = explode("=",$line,2);
    echo $v."<br />";
}
```

If you're running PHP 5.4, you can use the shorter:

```
foreach(file("data.txt") as $line) echo explode("=",$line,2)[1]."<br />";
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is always `name=WORD` then you can go with this:

```
$file = file('data.txt')

// iterate through every line:
foreach($file as $line) {
  // split at the '=' char
  $parts = explode('=', $line, 2); // limit to max 2 splits

  // and the get the second part of it
  echo $parts[1];
}
```

Comment: What happens if a line has `key=foo=bar`?

Answer (score 1):

If the data will always be in that or a similar format, you can use PHP's built-in [config file parser](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) to load the data and then refer to its values via array index.

```
$data = parse_ini_file( "data.txt" );
echo $data["name"]."\n";
```

No string manipulation or for loop required.